# Why does MozAudioAvailable's Framebuffer throw if I embed data directly?

Tags: javascript, security, audio, framebuffer

I read here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Security the following.

> The MozAudioAvailable event's frameBuffer attribute will throw if the origin of audio resource does not match the document's origin.

When I tried linking to an audio file in the same directory and then accessing MozAudioAvailable's Framebuffer, no security error was thrown. But when I tried to embed the data in the page and do the same, a security error was thrown. Why?

html-source: http://pastebin.com/6DrbNFv2

Answer (score 0):

It's enforcing the Same Origin Policy. You can view the details at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Basically, to not generate a security warning, content must be from the same location. Same location is defined as domain name, application layer protocol, and port number matching. In the case when your resources are in the same directory, these match. When embedded, they do not.

Comment: I fail to see how embedding this information creates another location, given your definition. Could you elaborate?